# Replace NA values using if statement based on group by

Tags: r

I am looking to do the following in a more elegant manner in R. I believe there is a way but just cant wrap my head around it. Following is the problem.

I have a df which contains NAs. However, I want to make the NAs into zeros where if the sum of the NA is not equal to zero and if the sum is NA then leave as NA. The example below should make it clear.

```
A<-c("A", "A", "A", "A", 
     "B","B","B","B",
     "C","C","C","C")
B<-c(1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,2,1,2,3)
data<-data.frame(A,B)
```

Following is how the data looks like

```
   A  B
1  A  1
2  A NA
3  A NA
4  A  1
5  B NA
6  B NA
7  B NA
8  B NA
9  C  2
10 C  1
11 C  2
12 C  3
```

And am looking to get a result as per the following

```
   A  B
1  A  1
2  A  0
3  A  0
4  A  1
5  B NA
6  B NA
7  B NA
8  B NA
9  C  2
10 C  1
11 C  2
12 C  3
```

I know I can use inner join by creating a table first and and then making an IF statement based on that table but I was wondering if there is a way to do it in one or two lines of code in R.

Following is the solution related to the inner join I was referring to

```
sum_NA <- function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_integer_ else sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)

data2 <- data %>% group_by(A) %>% summarize(x = sum_NA(B), Y = 
ifelse(is.na(x), TRUE, FALSE))
data2

data2_1 <- right_join(data, data2, by = "A")

data <- mutate(data2_1, B = ifelse(Y == FALSE & is.na(B), 0,B))
data <- select(data, - Y,-x)
data
```

Comment: "I am looking to do the following in a more elegant manner in R" -- more elegant than *what*? Why not share your current solution?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'if the sum of the NA is not equal to zero'?

Comment: @ErikKornet I took it as meaning e.g. if `sum(df$A[df$A == "A"], na.rm = TRUE) > 0`

Comment: I see.  If that's the case then @PoGibas 's answer below is a pretty good take!

Comment: I have added my solution in there. Clearly its a massive piece of code as compared to the solutions

Comment: @Molia It's a process of learning :-) Everyone starts somewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe solution like this would work:

```
data[is.na(B) & A %in% unique(na.omit(data)$A), ]$B <- 0
```

Here you're asking:

- if `B` is `NA`
- if `A` is within letters that have `non-NA` values

Then make those values `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Or similarly, with `ifelse()`:

```
data$B <- ifelse(is.na(data$B) & data$A %in% unique(na.omit(data)$A), 0, data$B)
```

Answer (score 2):

or with `dplyr` its:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(B=ifelse(is.na(B) & A %in% unique(na.omit(data)$A), 0, B))
```